# Is there a way to change the color of the keyboard back light on the lenovo y50

Tags: lenovo-laptop

Is it possible to change the back light of the keyboard on a Lenovo y50 laptop?. I cant seem to find the answer on my own.

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't possible:

> ... the side shafts of the island-style keys are made of translucent red plastic, and the light shines through the actual key bodies, rather than simply leaking from around the key cutouts, as in other backlit laptops.

Source: http://www.cnet.com/products/lenovo-y50-touch/